# Getting Checked Radio Value From A Single Form When There Are Multiple Forms On The Page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been struggling with this one for a few days, but we have an eCom site that has a bunch of forms per category page. All of the forms have at least one radio button checked by default, and everything about the forms (IDs, Classes, etc) are the same other than the radio imput value it seems.

Here's an example of just two products back to back, but each page has 10-20 products.

```
    <!-- start item-->
<div class="search-item">
  <div class="search-name">
    <b>
      <a class="LinkPageProduct" href='/products/absinthe-fragrance-oil.aspx'>Crafter's Choice™ Absinthe* Fragrance Oil 177</a>
    </b>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="Buy" action="/AddToCart.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return checkQuantity(this, 'QuantityText', 'Quantity must be a number greater than zero');">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 0px;" nowrap>
        <div class="" style="padding-bottom: 6px; font-family: roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="31671" />$7.16 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$9.54</span> for 2 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="31672" />$11.98 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$15.97</span> for 4 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="46961" />$20.60 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$27.47</span> for 8 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="31673" />$37.93 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$50.57</span> for 16 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="55132" />$69.74 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$92.98</span> for 32 fl. oz (2-16 oz Size) <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="37308" />
          <span style="color:#55A6D3">$583.84 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$614.57</span> for 25 lb. drum (Bulk) </span>
          <br />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 7px;">
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlOOSQty_0">
                <input type="text" id="QuantityText" name="QuantityText" style="text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 20px; font-size: 15px" onfocus="if (this.value == 'QTY') this.value = '';" value="1" />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;">
              <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ChildContent$SearchResults$ParentData$ctl00$btnAddToCart" type="submit" id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_btnAddToCart_0" class="button pink medium" value="+ Add To Basket    " style="width: 147px" />
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlAddToWish_0">
                <input name="btnAddToWishlist" id="btnAddToWishlist" class="button white medium" type="submit" value="+ Add To Wish List" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 147px" />
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id="WishProductID" name="WishProductID" value="8556" />
</form>
<!-- end item-->
<p></p><br>
<!-- start item-->
<div class="search-item">
  <div class="search-name">
    <b>
      <a class="LinkPageProduct" href='/products/acai-berries-satin-fragrance-oil.aspx'>Crafter's Choice™ Acai Berries & Satin* Fragrance Oil 415</a>
    </b>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="Buy" action="/AddToCart.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return checkQuantity(this, 'QuantityText', 'Quantity must be a number greater than zero');">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 0px;" nowrap>
        <div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 8px">
          <a href="/store-search.aspx?Sale=1" id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_lnkSale_3" class="LeftNavCategoryLinks" style="text-decoration: none; padding-left: 0px; color: #EE4375;">Sale!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="removefrommobile desktop-only" style="padding-bottom:6px;font-family:roboto, sans-serif;font-size:13px;">-->
        <div class="" style="padding-bottom: 6px; font-family: roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="30851" />$7.30 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$9.73</span> for 2 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="30852" />$11.01 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$14.68</span> for 4 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="46850" />$18.64 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$24.85</span> for 8 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="30853" />$34.04 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$45.38</span> for 16 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="55004" />$61.94 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$82.59</span> for 32 fl. oz (2-16 oz Size) <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="37195" />
          <span style="color:#55A6D3">$525.45 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$553.11</span> for 25 lb. drum (Bulk) </span>
          <br />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
        <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 7px;">
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlOOSQty_3">
                <input type='text' id='QuantityText' name='QuantityText' style="text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 20px; font-size: 15px" onfocus="if (this.value == 'QTY') this.value = '';" value='1'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;">
              <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ChildContent$SearchResults$ParentData$ctl03$btnAddToCart" type="submit" id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_btnAddToCart_3" class="button pink medium" value="+ Add To Basket    " style="width: 147px" />
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlAddToWish_3">
                <input name="btnAddToWishlist" id="btnAddToWishlist" class="button white medium" type='submit' value="+ Add To Wish List" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 147px" />
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlBulkProduct_3">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlHSProduct_3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id='WishProductID' name='WishProductID' value="6043" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to come up with a vanilla JS function that will return the radio input value of the specific radio input that the 'Add to basket' button is clicked on.

So, using the example DOM from above, if they added the top product to the basket, I would be looking for just that radio button input value, or the same thing if they added the bottom product, but not both.

I started with some pretty basic stuff such as

```
function() {
  return document.querySelector('[name="ProductPriceIDText"]:checked').value
}
```

But of course the problem there is that it's just grabbing the first checked radio button on the page.

Of course if I use All, as in...

```
function() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('[name="ProductPriceIDText"]:checked').value
}
```

Then it comes back undefined naturally.

I feel like there has be be a way to walk back from a querySelector of the button to button.form, then form.queryselector with the :checked to grab the radio value, but I just can't get the logic together to get there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the `button`, find `closest` `<form>`, then do your query selector.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[type=submit]").forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var radio = button.closest("form").querySelector('[type=radio]:checked');
    console.log (radio ? radio.value : "nothing selected")
  })

})
```

```html
<!-- start item-->
<div class="search-item">
  <div class="search-name">
    <b>
      <a class="LinkPageProduct" href='/products/absinthe-fragrance-oil.aspx'>Crafter's Choice™ Absinthe* Fragrance Oil 177</a>
    </b>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="Buy" action="/AddToCart.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return checkQuantity(this, 'QuantityText', 'Quantity must be a number greater than zero');">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 0px;" nowrap>
        <div class="" style="padding-bottom: 6px; font-family: roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="31671" />$7.16 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$9.54</span> for 2 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="31672" />$11.98 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$15.97</span> for 4 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="46961" />$20.60 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$27.47</span> for 8 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="31673" />$37.93 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$50.57</span> for 16 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="55132" />$69.74 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$92.98</span> for 32 fl. oz (2-16 oz Size) <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="37308" />
          <span style="color:#55A6D3">$583.84 <span style="padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;">$614.57</span> for 25 lb. drum (Bulk) </span>
          <br />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 7px;">
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlOOSQty_0">
                <input type="text" id="QuantityText" name="QuantityText" style="text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 20px; font-size: 15px" onfocus="if (this.value == 'QTY') this.value = '';" value="1" />
              </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;">
              <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ChildContent$SearchResults$ParentData$ctl00$btnAddToCart" type="submit" id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_btnAddToCart_0" class="button pink medium" value="+ Add To Basket    " style="width: 147px"
              />
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlAddToWish_0">
                <input name="btnAddToWishlist" id="btnAddToWishlist" class="button white medium" type="submit" value="+ Add To Wish List" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 147px" />
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id="WishProductID" name="WishProductID" value="8556" />
</form>
<!-- end item-->
<p></p><br>
<!-- start item-->
<div class="search-item">
  <div class="search-name">
    <b>
      <a class="LinkPageProduct" href='/products/acai-berries-satin-fragrance-oil.aspx'>Crafter's Choice™ Acai Berries & Satin* Fragrance Oil 415</a>
    </b>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="Buy" action="/AddToCart.aspx" method="post" onsubmit="return checkQuantity(this, 'QuantityText', 'Quantity must be a number greater than zero');">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 0px;" nowrap>
        <div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 8px">
          <a href="/store-search.aspx?Sale=1" id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_lnkSale_3" class="LeftNavCategoryLinks" style="text-decoration: none; padding-left: 0px; color: #EE4375;">Sale!&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
        <!--<div class="removefrommobile desktop-only" style="padding-bottom:6px;font-family:roboto, sans-serif;font-size:13px;">-->
        <div class="" style="padding-bottom: 6px; font-family: roboto, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="30851" />$7.30 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$9.73</span> for 2 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="30852" />$11.01 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$14.68</span> for 4 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="46850" />$18.64 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$24.85</span> for 8 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="30853" />$34.04 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$45.38</span> for 16 fl. oz <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="55004" />$61.94 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$82.59</span> for 32 fl. oz (2-16 oz Size) <br />
          <input type="radio" name="ProductPriceIDText" id="ProductPriceIDText" value="37195" />
          <span style="color:#55A6D3">$525.45 <span style='padding-left:3px;color:#E03965;text-decoration:line-through;'>$553.11</span> for 25 lb. drum (Bulk) </span>
          <br />
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-top: 0px;">
        <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0'>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom: 10px;"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-top: 1px; padding-left: 7px;">
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlOOSQty_3">
                <input type='text' id='QuantityText' name='QuantityText' style="text-align: center; width: 30px; height: 20px; font-size: 15px" onfocus="if (this.value == 'QTY') this.value = '';" value='1'>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;">
              <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$ChildContent$SearchResults$ParentData$ctl03$btnAddToCart" type="submit" id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_btnAddToCart_3" class="button pink medium" value="+ Add To Basket    " style="width: 147px"
              />
              <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlAddToWish_3">
                <input name="btnAddToWishlist" id="btnAddToWishlist" class="button white medium" type='submit' value="+ Add To Wish List" style="margin-top: 5px; width: 147px" />
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlBulkProduct_3">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="MainContent_ChildContent_SearchResults_ParentData_pnlHSProduct_3"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="hidden" id='WishProductID' name='WishProductID' value="6043" />
</form>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really answer the question. But it answers a more abstract question. For the topic starter's benefit, in GTM, you would want to have something similar to the usage of .closest here, but no need to trouble yourself with the event listener, GTM already deploys all the needed listeners. Just use the `{{Click Element}}` as a handle here.